# How do I print out individual words within my list?

Tags: python

I am trying to print each word from my list onto separate lines, however it is printing each letter onto individual lines

```
Words = sentence.strip()
for word in sentence:
    print (word)
```

My full code (for anyone wondering) is:

```
import csv
file = open("Task2.csv", "w")
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
Words = sentence.strip()
for word in sentence:
    print (word)
for s in Words:
    Positions = Words.index(s)+1
    file.write(str(Words) + (str(Positions) + "\n"))
file.close()
```

Comment: Use `.split()` with `.strip()`

Comment: Don't use `.index()` for position, will return the first position only (if you have duplicated letters), use `enumerate()` instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to used [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead of [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) only removes the leading and trailing whitespaces in a string:

```
>>> my_string = '  This is a sentence.   '
>>> my_string.strip()
'This is a sentence.'
```

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) does what you want which is return a list of the words in the string; by default, using whitespace as the delimiter string:

```
>>> my_string = '  This is a sentence.   '
>>> my_string.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence.']
```

So, your code should look more like:

```
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You  forgot to split sentence and use "Words" not "sentence" in first for loop.

```
#file = open("Task2.csv", "w")
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
Words = sentence.split()
for word in Words:
    print (word)
for s in Words:
    Positions = Words.index(s)+1
    #file.write(str(Words) + (str(Positions) + "\n"))
#file.close()
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Please enter a sentence: I am Dinesh
I
am
Dinesh

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```